# Округление суммы до двух знаков после запятой в SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Условие задачи:

> Используя таблицу purchase_order_header, вычислите, сколько денег
> потратили клиенты на заказы в каждом месяце 2012 года. В итоговую
> таблицу войдут два поля: название месяца (в нижнем регистре) и
> суммарные траты за месяц, округлённые до двух знаков после запятой.
> Отсортируйте результаты по убыванию числа трат.
> Решение:

```
SELECT 
    LOWER(TO_CHAR(order_date, 'Month')) AS month, 
    ROUND(SUM(subtotal), 2) AS total
FROM adventure.purchase_order_header
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2012
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

вроде бы решение верное, но я получаю не округленное значение в поле **total**:

```
month   total
january 700407
march   646976
june    511208
...     ...
```

причем, с другими агрегатными функциями, например, с **MIN**, **MAX** и т.д. округление проходит нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: *я получаю не округленное значение в поле total* Для требования "округлённые до двух знаков после запятой" показанные значения - округлённые.

Comment: нет, сейчас значение округляется до целого. В таблице поле subtotal имеет 4 знака после запятой, мне же нужно округлить до двух.

Comment: Попробовал, округляет правильно. Не может быть такого, что просто суммы за месяц как раз являются целым числом? Попробуйте рядом вывести просто поле с суммой без округления

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим оратором. А ещё - в учебных заданиях обычно округлять надо не итоговую сумму, а каждый отдельный элемент. Т.е. не `ROUND(SUM())`, a `SUM(ROUND())`..

Comment: Всем спасибо, что нашли время в новогодние праздники. Проблема была в структуре данных таблицы